# Adding Comma seperator to the input field number displays as NAN

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

The commas are getting added correctly, but I'm getting this error message in the console:

> "The specified value "NaN" is not a valid number"

I tried by making it as `type="number"`, still the same warning.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var extra = 0;
  var $input = jQuery(".total_crm_records");

  $input.on("keyup", function(event) {

    // When user select text in the document, also abort.
    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    if (selection !== '') {
      return;
    }

    // When the arrow keys are pressed, abort.
    if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, [38, 40, 37, 39]) !== -1) {
      if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        extra = 1000;
      } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        extra = -1000;
      } else {
        return;
      }

    }

    var $this = jQuery(this);
    // Get the value.
    var input = $this.val();
    var input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, "");
    input = input ? parseInt(input, 10) : 0;
    input += extra;
    extra = 0;
    $this.val(function() {
      return (input === 0) ? "" : input.toLocaleString("en-US");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input field : <input type="text" data-type="number" maxlength="20" class="total_crm_records">
```

Comment: *Where* is *saying* that? *How* you make it *say* that? I've typed some numbers and it works fine for me.

Comment: Yeah @DontVoteMeDown is right. I also couldn't find out

Comment: You might have an english centered view on number formats. E.g. in Germany the thousands separator is a dot or a space and the decimal separator is a comma. Confusing, huh? You might want to rely on Number.prototype.ftoLocaleString() https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString